# How to have a point translate to a point of a Rectangle even when the rectangle resizes in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the image below, i want the small black rectangle to cover the Green Color Heart Button on the top right.  The black rectangle should resize and cover the heart image when the size of the main image changes.

How can I do something like this with SwiftUI?

What I have tried to figure out so far:

1. I think I need some way to translate the point-size of the rectangle to resize to the size of the resizing image. I do not know how to do this with SwiftUI
2. I think I need need a `GeometryReader` in some way?

Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `GeometryReader` in an overlay.

```swift
    var body: some View {
            Color.green.frame(width: 320, height: 320) // Pretend this is your image
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                            Color.clear // Fill the whole space
                            Color.red // Your desired overlay
                                .frame(width: proxy.frame(in: .local).width/10.0,  // Whatever proportions you want
                                       height: proxy.frame(in: .local).height/10.0)
                        }
                    })
    }
```

[image]